# Adding buttons with multi line text but both lines having center paragraph alignment

Tags: java, html, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to create a button that has two lines of text in it. This is easy enough to do using the `<br/>` tags in `<html>` however the larger line is center aligned but the smaller line is floating left:

[image]

Below is my code for generating this button (I've wrapped the text so it doesn't look ugly). Is it possible to get the first line `"View Config File"` to appear centrally aligned, keeping the central alignment for the second line?

```
    JButton viewConfigFile = new JButton("<html>View Config File" + 
    "<br/>Be careful of any changes made</html>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original suggestion was to use the `center` tag to wrap the text but Pete pointed out this tag is obsolete and deprecated in HTML 4 (so I don't recommend to use this).

```
JButton button = new JButton("<html><center>View Config File" 
    + "<br/>Be careful of any changes made</center></html>");
```

Instead you can use the CSS text-align property:

```
JButton button = new JButton("<html><div text-align:center>View Config File" + "<br/>Be careful of any changes made</div></html>");
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: @Pete, thanks, I'm only know HTML basics. Answer updated.

Comment: ah wasn't sure if it converted the tag or not - your html need to be `style="text-align:center"`